# yo generator installation error: "the package yo does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried install the yo generator for angular-full-stack.

But I just got the following error:

> "the package yo does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies
>   requirements!"

Comment: ive tried to update my yo version and it worked :)